# Can I use HTTP secure In Image Source?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Can I use https in windows phone 8 Image source?

Code:

```
<Image Source="https://www.ppp.com/picture/th.jpg" Height="80" Width="80" />
```

If I use http://, it will work.

---

**Update:**

Yes, it works now because I enable fiddler https decryption on.

Comment: Have you tried it yourself? Do you want something beyond a yes or a no?

Comment: Only if the server supports SSL (https), and the SSL certificate is valid.

Comment: @MarceloCantos I have tried it, but is in emulator with fiddler on.

Comment: @Matthew It could be because of fiddler https decryption.

Comment: @KevFixx: For future reference, don't leave your audience guessing at important factors like what you've tried and the operational environment. Nothing in your question hinted that you'd tried https or what symptoms you experienced. Nor did you mention that it was in the emulator and that you had Fiddler running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be no different. Assuming the server is using/supports `https`, as in the URL is correct, and there is no authentication anything needed, then it should work fine.

---

As the commenters pointed out, are you asking a yes-no question or are you having trouble?

Comment: I just need is should it work, and possible a solution for it.

Comment: @KevFixx Does it not work? I tried the link you gave and both HTTP and HTTPS gave a "file not found" error.

Comment: Sorry, that is just a example.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, here is the doc that describes what you can use in it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 1):

There are no differences. You can use it without problems!

> Cross-domain URIs are permitted, and specifying the scheme is
>   permitted, but mixing URI schemes (such as accessing an HTTPS image
>   from a Silverlight plug-in hosted on an HTTP-served HTML page) is not
>   permitted.